# How to decouple microservice client from Spring framework

Tags: spring, microservices, resttemplate

We have some microservices written with spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE.
For these microservices we provide an independent client module based on RestTemplate.

However, another project aiming at using the microservice client is based on an old version of Spring, thus, importing the microservice-client dependency would result on a version conflict of spring-web. Is there some techniques to decouple framework dependencies from RestTemplate based clients?

Comment: any possibility the other project can use feign clients to call your services instead of using your client on higher spring version?

Comment: Maybe, it depends if feigns brings us flexibility enough. What would be the point to use another HTTP client? let's say a third project with another spring/feign version needs to communicate with the microservice. Wouldn't the issue be the same?

Comment: Communication between feign client and microservice will happen through REST calls. so there will not be any dependency on spring versions at client  side and at microservice. Feign clients remove a lot of boilerplate code which you have with Rest Templates and are quite easy to use.